# Which .NET framework for complex logging in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, logging, error-handling

I've searched over this portal and I actually couldn't find answer to this question. I'm looking for some kind of framework which allow me to log users' state and behaviour, especially values they've entered on forms, session state, cookies, etc... Everything that might help as much as possible to reconstruct application state and recreate error situations with as less configuration as possible.

Prefered open-source solutions.

Comment: well, there is intellitrace which is excellent... not open source though, more part of VS.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx

Comment: But it's available on Ultimate only, I have Professional version

Comment: pay for it :-P (joking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For application and user state your are probably going to have to design something yourself.

For general web state you can take a look at [ELMAH](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) which will give you some level of details.

In the past I built one for myself that would take info from various environments variables depending on the kind of the application you are running (desktop, web and wcf service).

If you find better approaches, please share.

Comment: I do recommend also ELMAH. but for app state, most likely... custom stuff.

Comment: I like ELMAH, but I still think it's poor in what it gives you. Maybe there's a space here for something new. Log4Net is awesome, but is too raw and that's where I think the problem lies. It's hard to define a logging format for every type of data a developer might want to log. So it would have to be a combination of getting environmental information (ELMAH++) and offering custom loggers like Log4Net.

Comment: agreed. I think every developer has their own way and their own requirements hence why you should either create your own or... pay and use intellitrace

Comment: Intellitrace for production logging?

Comment: yup. as long as you switch it off!!!. Trust me. Even the MS guys say it and have said it before. that's really the way to capture some live stuff